# ASP.Net MVC Core ValidationSummary always shows Partial view errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, razor

We have a main form with some basic inputs and a partial view rendered in a Boostrap Modal dialog:

```
@model CreateDonutVm
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Donut";
}

<div id="homer-search-modal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" id="homerSearchModalContent">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_SearchHomer.cshtml", Model.HomerSearch)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form asp-controller="Donuts" asp-action="Create">
    <fieldset class="with-legend">
        <legend>Donut Details</legend>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Donut.BoughtBy, "", new {@class = "col-sm-1 col-form-label-sm"})
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Donut.BoughtBy, "", new {@class = "form-control form-control-sm"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix">
        @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Donut Creation failed. Please correct these errors:")
            </div>
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Models:

```
public class CreateDonutVm
{
    public CreateDonutVm()
    {
        HomerSearch = new HomerSearchVm();
    }

    public HomerSearchVm HomerSearch { get; set; }
    public DonutDto Donut { get; set; }
}

public class DonutDto
{
    [Required]
    public string BoughtBy { get; set; }
}

public class HomerSearchVm
{
    [Required]
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the partial view needs its own Model, containing a search term which the user fills and then submits back to the controller to find a list of entities. Within the partial view, the user selects the desired entity. The entity ID and Name are then pushed back into the form on the main page.

When the user clicks the 'Save' button on the main form, we don't want the validation messages from the partial view being shown (those errors are handled within the modal form).

I've looked far and wide but can't find an example of someone achieving this.

I initially assumed that because the partial view is rendered outside the form that contains the ValidationSummary control, then it MVC wouldn't assess the state of the controls in the partials.

However, looking at ModelState after submitting the main form, MVC is assessing the partial view controls and putting errors in the ModelState.Errors collection for those partial view controls.

Is there a way to get MVC to only assess the controls in the main form and ignore those in the partial views?

Answer (score 1):

It's not about what's in the `form` tag; it matters what's in your model. When you submit, none of the values for `HomerSearch` will be posted, because they're not in the form that's being posted, *but*, they are still part of your model, and if there's required fields an such in that, then your model will fail validation as a result.

That said, properties on reference properties like your `HomeSearch` prop are only validated if the reference prop is non-null. That *should* be the default, but it's likely that you're newing it up in the view model constructor or by using a default value on the prop. Simply, you should stop that if you don't want it to participate in validation. However, that may not be possible based on the rest of your code. If something else is depending on this being set to an instance, then you'll break that code.

Long and short, the whole approach here is probably wrong. More likely than not, this should be broken off your view model and instead included in the page via a view component.

Comment: The partial view contains markup for a search control within another form, where the user enters in a search phrase to a textbox, clicks Search, gets shown a grid of entities, and then selects an entity. The ID and Name of the selected entity is then pushed back into the form on the main page. So it seems to me that a View Component isn't appropriate here because we need the partial view have a model we can bind the search phrase and entity result set to. Do you have any other suggestions on how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not very clear because you don't show your model and the validation error...

But when you submit the form and pass the `Model`, then the model has to be valid... assuming  `HomerSearch` has a required field that has not been filled, your `Model` is not valid and therefore should not be submitted... if `HomeSearch` is not inside the form then it would not be included in your model... but then if your `Model` requires some value from `HomeSearch` then you would get the validation error...

It sounds like you need to refactor your design... you can:

- don't pass the entire Model to the controller, just pass `Donut`
- remove `HomerSearch` validations...
- use custom/conditional validation rules

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ValidationSummary to true, it seems to work in a partial view scenario where you don't want the validations on the 1st page, but definitely on the partial 2nd page. This is MVC 5 .NET 6.0.

```
<h5>@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</h5>
ModelState.AddModelError("Security", "error message. ");
return View("_LoadAgentSetting", agentsettings);
```